# Why are these IF statement not working?

Tags: bash, shell

I have two IF Statements that should be 'Hitting/Triggering', but something isn't kosher in my code. I'm just learning BASH, and appreciate any help.

I have two arrays created, earlier in code,

```
#Array of Dates
DATES=($(awk -F'/' '{print $2}' "${TEMPFILE}"))
#Array of IP's
IPS=($(awk '{print $2}' "${TEMPFILE}"))
```

Since they are created from the same file, they have the same length.

Example of two arrays:

```
01 06 07 08 11 23 24
192.168.0.4 192.168.0.6 192.168.0.4 192.168.0.5 192.168.0.6 192.168.0.4 192.168.0.5
```

In my statement i am parsing through a Bluecoat log, and the IF statements will check to see if the IP has changed from the arrays (formed from a DHCP log parsing). **Everything seems to work (seeing results in output) except that the IF statements aren't being triggered, so the IP never changes.**

Here is my code for searching an entire month( a day at a time)

```
ARRAY_COUNTER=1

NEW_GREP_TERM=${IPS[0]}

for i in {01..31}
do
    SEARCHPATH=${BASEPATH}/${DEF_YEAR}${DEF_MONTH}/SG_OIG__22[8-9]${DEF_MONTH}${i}*
    zgrep --no-filename $NEW_GREP_TERM $SEARCHPATH | awk -f /usr/local/bin/cvsit.awk >> $OUTFILE 

        if [[ "${i}" == "${DATES[$ARRAY_COUNTER]}" ]]; then

            if [[ "${IPS[$ARRAY_COUNTER]}" != "${IPS[$ARRAY_COUNTER-1]}"  ]]; then
                echo -e "Change IP"
                NEW_GREP_TERM=${IPS[$ARRAY_COUNTER]}
                zgrep --no-filename $NEW_GREP_TERM $SEARCHPATH | awk -f /usr/local/bin/cvsit.awk >> $OUTFILE 

            fi
        ARRAY_COUNTER++
        fi
done
```

Comment: Can you paste a sample of the input so we can run the script? See [Short, Self Contained Correct Example](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Assert that `DATES` contains what you expect. Assert that `i` contains what you expect. Input, observed output, expected output. Minimize the amount of code necessary to exhibit your observed problem. Debugging 101.

Comment: Try running in debug mode (using `set -x`) and see the value therein.

Comment: you should change `ARRAY_COUNTER++` with `let ARRAY_COUNTER++`

Comment: thats @blue i saw that after i posted the code...

Comment: @tim you should change it in the question too. Try adding `echo "something"` inside the first if and outside the second, to check whether at least the first condition is ever met, and let us know. I don't have the source files to test it myself so..

Comment: You may want to add the `-f` flag to your calls to `zgrep` as an optimization and to avoid possible corner cases, since the periods in the IP addresses will be interpreted as regular-expression metacharacters, not literal periods.

Comment: What does `echo $IFS | cat -vte` say?

Comment: You might need to change `${IPS[$ARRAY_COUNTER-1]}` to `${IPS[$((ARRAY_COUNTER-1))]}` for arithmetic evaluation. Right now it's appending `-1` to `$ARRAY_COUNTER` methinks.

Comment: i'm evaluating using the debug command at the moment...

Comment: @doubleDown An expression inside a `[...]` is in an arithmetic context so no need for `$((...))` inside it. Should be as simple as `${IPS[ARRAY_COUNTER - 1]}` in order to index the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need double `(( ))` around anything that does maths in bash.

So, instead of

```
ARRAY_COUNTER++
```

you need

```
(( ARRAY_COUNTER++ ))
```

Here's the full script:

```
ARRAY_COUNTER=1

NEW_GREP_TERM=${IPS[0]}

for i in {01..31}
do
    SEARCHPATH=${BASEPATH}/${DEF_YEAR}${DEF_MONTH}/SG_OIG__22[8-9]${DEF_MONTH}${i}*
    zgrep --no-filename $NEW_GREP_TERM $SEARCHPATH | awk -f /usr/local/bin/cvsit.awk >> $OUTFILE 

        if [[ "${i}" == "${DATES[$ARRAY_COUNTER]}" ]]; then

            if [[ "${IPS[$ARRAY_COUNTER]}" != "${IPS[$ARRAY_COUNTER-1]}"  ]]; then
                echo -e "Change IP"
                NEW_GREP_TERM=${IPS[$ARRAY_COUNTER]}
                zgrep --no-filename $NEW_GREP_TERM $SEARCHPATH | awk -f /usr/local/bin/cvsit.awk >> $OUTFILE 

            fi
        (( ARRAY_COUNTER++ ))
        fi
done
```